# Querying if a model instance has any of a specified set of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I want to write a method for a model (in this case, the Participant model) that looks at a certain set of its associations and simply notes whether any exist. Here is what I have:

```
  def post_screener_associations?
    ParticipantAuthorizationForm.where(:participant_id => self.id).count > 0
    ParticipantConsent.where(:participant_id => self.id).count > 0
    # and so on exactly like the format above about 8 more times!
  end
```

I know there is a better way to write this query but I don't want to bug my co-workers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def post_screener_associations?
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.all? { |a| send(a.name).present? }
  end
```

This should ask on every association is it present and if all present method will return true, in another way it will be false

Answer (score 0):

Another option in case you don't want to use reflection.  It's similar to your original post, simplifying it using active record methods you have on the participant model.

```
def post_screeener_associations?
  participant_authorization_form.present? ||
  participant_consent.present? ||
  # etc.
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was really looking for. I knew there was a cleaner way to get the result.